# Bootstrap horizontal form not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a simple horizontal form with bootstrap for my laravel application. This is the code I'm using. But it displays it like this:

[image: form is displayed on the left halve of the page]

The form is displayed on the left half of the page. Any ideas? Preferably the form should be centered on the page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

      <!-- Form Name -->
      <legend>Register</legend>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Password input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Password input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-enter Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="submit"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following bootstrap code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">your div</div>
```

So, basic idea is that divide all columns by 3 meaning there are total 12 bootstrap columns and if you divide it by 4, it gives you 3 columns. Then put your div in middle column.Meaning `col-md-4`  makes one column of 4 bootstrap columns.

Try this: I have tried with IntelliJ Idea and it works fine in my browser. let me know what did not work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <fieldset>
           <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Register</legend>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="email">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Password input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Password input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-enter Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: already tried this...placed the form inside a div like that..didn't work.

Comment: @HussainNoorMohamed I have update the code, let me know what did not work.

Comment: @Young is also right as you have to adjust the control field but form is placed in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>

          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend>Register</legend>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="email">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-enter Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="submit"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
```

`col-sm-6 control-label` =>`col-sm-3 control-label`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
   <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Register</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="email">
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Password input-->
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Password input-->
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-enter Password" class="form-control input-md"
       required="" type="password">
     </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="submit"></label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
     </div>
    </div>

   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Running your code snippet shows that your solution doesn't work either.